# Examples of Borel probability measures on the Schwartz function space?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, schwartz-distributions, gaussian

Let $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be the Frechet space of Schwartz functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Its dual space $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is the space of tempered distributions.

Minlos Theorem as stated in [ME](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4729855/proof-of-the-bochner-minlos-theorem-for-the-schwartz-space) then provide examples of Borel probability measures on $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

As for $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$, any symmetric, positive definite trace-class operator (a.k.a $S$-operator) yields a unique Borel Gaussian probability measure on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

Now, I wonder if there are corresponding examples of Borel probability measures on the Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ as opposed to $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d)$ or $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

I searched for relevant references myself, but have not been successful. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Could you please show a reference for existence of Gaussian measures on $L^2$?

Comment: @tsnao   Gaussian Measures in Hilbert Space - Alexander Kukush

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\newcommand\S{\mathcal S}\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$$\S(\R^d)$ is a [complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space#Properties) [nuclear separable](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/124119/is-c-infty0-1-or-s-separable#comment319997_124119) metrizable locally convex vector space. So, by part (i) of the Corollary on p. 19 and part (a) of the Corollary on p. 2 in the [paper by Vakhania and Tarieladze](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/1123001), the class of the covariance operators of Borel Gaussian measures over $\S(\R^d)$ coincides with the class of all symmetric positive operators mapping $\S'(\R^d)$ into $\S(\R^d)$.